# How to set the enable/disable the Kendo client control from c# / server side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have set enable / disable for the Kendo Calendar Control in the Jquery.

$("#SurgeryDate").data('kendoDatePicker').enable(false);

How to set the enable/disable the Kendo client control from c# / server side?

Comment: You cannot directly enable/disable from server side. You could only use arguments loading page first time in razor. Or use ajax call to get the enable/disable state from serverside and then set this state on client side.

Comment: @MantasČekanauskas he can also add a flag property to the page's viewModel and disable the widget at it's initialization based on that. It is another option.

Comment: How do i get the control property in the view model ? I can do the database property value by setting default value in the view model